# I can't figure out why my linked lists don't work

Tags: java

here is what I am trying to do to get it back out.

```
        linked n = stu;

        int d = datainput.readInt();
        for(int x = 0; x < d; x++){
            students student = new students();
            student.setlname(datainput.readUTF());
            student.setfname(datainput.readUTF());
            student.setAge(datainput.readShort());
            student.setSex(datainput.readChar());
            student.setRace(datainput.readChar());

            int coucounter = datainput.readInt();
            linked cou = student.getCou();
            for(int y = 0; y < coucounter; y++){
                System.out.print("WTF");
                courses course = new courses();
                course.setName(datainput.readUTF());
                course.setDept(datainput.readUTF());
                course.setHours(datainput.readShort());
                course.setGrade(datainput.readChar());
                cou.setObject(course);  //Something wrong here
                cou = cou.getNext();

            }
            n.setObject(student);
            n = n.getNext();

        }
```

EDIT: Here is my linked class

```
public class linked {
    private Object ob;
    private linked next;

    linked(){
    }

    void setNext(linked l){
        next = l;
    }

    void setObject(Object o){
        ob = o;
    }

    linked getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    Object getObject(){
        return ob;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and how do you know it isn't working?

Comment: Any reason why you favor serialization over standard formats like CSV, XML or JSON for which there are countless parsers available which enables you to do the job in a single code line? Homework?

Comment: How does it not work? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: I know it isn't working because it is making a null pointer exception. And yes this is homework. It worked fine before I restructured it so everything was in linked lists. 

What is expected is it doesn't create a null pointer exception. After this finishes I should be able to pull the values from the objects for use in JTextFields and allow people to edit them.

Comment: i'm assuming student.getCou(); is throwning the NPE? And what is a 'linked' type ? You call getNext() on it, but have you allocated it, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Nope. It actually prints the "WTF" once before erroring.

Comment: Which line are you getting the NPE on?

Comment: I don't know. It eventually falls out to the main method and doesn't give me any information. If I get rid of the loop and make it run once I have a student object successfully residing in the linked list head and I am able to reference it properly.

Comment: I found the exact line is it messed up on. The cou.setObject(course) is the line. A shame java wouldn't just tell me that.

Comment: So the actual problem was that you was unable to interpret the exception+stacktrace. In future questions, post the exception+stacktrace and point the line in the code where it's been caused. Don't just say "it doesn't work". Exceptions+traces namely tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once a cause is *understood*, a solution is nothing more than obvious :)

Comment: @BakusC The exception and stack trace gave no useful output. If it would have I wouldn't have spent so long trying to fix it. It wasn't even pointing to the same module

Comment: @DasWood: I've never seen a stacktrace print totally unrelated stack frames in my entire Java career. I doubt that it gave bogus information. The usual reason for stuff like that is that one of your other assumptions is wrong. For example, you might have forgotten to recompile after your last edit or something similar.

Comment: No. I did clean and build multiple times. I use netbeans so it saves an recompiles every time.

Comment: Sounds like you misread the stack trace. You won't believe the number of SO questions where someone's like, "and here's the useless stack trace" and the answer is "stack trace tells you exactly what's wrong on line X". I've pretty much learned, if someone is here asking a question and claims "Oh, no need to see X, it shows nothing important", you should **never** believe them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it.

```
                cou.setObject(course);
                cou.setNext(new linked());
                cou = cou.getNext();
```

and

```
            n.setObject(student);
            n.setNext(new linked());
            n = n.getNext();
```

odd since when I used my linked lists before I didn't need to do this and the class is exactly the same. Oh well! Works now! WOOT